# Documentation for Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, documentation, mapreduce, version

I'm starting with Hadoop framework, my task is to write map-reduce application for the framework and and submit it. I have to use version 0.22.0 of Hadoop. I'm just learning basic concepts and API. However I find it **very** hard to learn it and to program some prototypes because both [the official documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/mapreduce/r0.22.0/index.html) and [API javadocs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.22.0/api/index.html) are outdated, incomplete, generally chaotic and even non-existing.

Here are just few thinks that I do not understand: [The MapReduce tutorial for Hadoop 0.22.0](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/mapreduce/current/mapred_tutorial.html) uses constructor ([here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/mapreduce/current/mapred_tutorial.html#Example%3A+WordCount+v2.0), line 101) of class [`Job`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/mapreduce/current/api/index.html) that is deprecated. All other constructors are also deprecated. There is no note in the javadocs about what is to be used instead. There are static methods of class `Job` that return instance of `Job` but those methods are undocumented and they require instance of poorly documented class [`Cluster`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/mapreduce/current/api/index.html) as parameter. So after reading all that mess I still don't know how to properly get instance of `Job`. Any help on this is appreciated.

When I tried to find out the answer in tutorial to later versions like 1.0.4 stable I found out that mapreduce tutorial for that version uses all the classes from package `org.apache.hadoop.mapred` that are deprecated in version 0.22.0. So 0.22.0 is more resent then 1.0.4. Please help me understand this. Or suggest some better resources.

Comment: close voter please leave comment explaining your vote. Especially when the close vote was so fast that I doubt that the voter could read first paragraph before voting...

Comment: If you need to use 0.22.0 why are you posting links to docs, or paying any attention to, the current API docs? Also note that tutorials are often not updated as quickly as APIs are. Also note that 1.0.4 was released in Oct of this year, while 0.22.0 was [released in Dec 2011](http://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html#10+December%2C+2011%3A+release+0.22.0+available), so I'm not sure what you're talking about. If you want to use an old version, you'll need to find old docs/tutorials. Not sure how the API docs for a version can be "outdated", they're created from the code.

Comment: @DaveNewton it's all explained in the question. Because the tutorial for 0.22.0 was outdated (using deprecated constructor) I had a look on tutorial for stable version - I expected it would reflect the changes better. In the fact it was even more outdated, using classes that were deprecated for a long time. Actually the tutorial for 1.0.4 is much less accurate for that version that the tutorial of 0.22.0 would be for 1.0.4. So why didn't they just copy the one from 0.22.0? It does not make any sense to me...

Comment: Once again I ask those down voting and those who have voted to close to leave comment explaining their decision. This question is absolutely in line with SO rules pronounced in FAQ. **Read twice before you vote to close something!** At least when you see that the user who posted the question is no newbie that does not know the rules (certainly not my case). And if you do, leave a comment so the owner can fix the problem. **Be constructive, be good SO user.**

Comment: If you have an issue, take it to meta-complaining here is pointless and noisesome.

Comment: Do you have this file: hadoop-0.22.0.tar.gz ? If you don't have, you can download it from here: archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/hadoop-0.22.0 , then unpack it, and you will find documents of hadoop 0.22.0. In details, the 'common docs' is under 'hadoop0.22.0/common/docs/', the 'hdfs docs' is under 'hadoop0.22.0/hdfs/docs/', the 'mapreduce docs' is under 'hadoop0.22.0/mapreduce/docs'. Good luck:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Javadoc](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/mapreduce/r0.22.0/api/index.html) might be a bit confusing, therefore having a look at the source of the [Job](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapred/0.22.0/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.java/?v=source) class will probably help you:

```
  ...
  @Deprecated
  public Job() throws IOException {
    this(new Configuration());
  }

  @Deprecated
  public Job(Configuration conf) throws IOException {
    this(new Cluster(conf), conf);
  }

  @Deprecated
  public Job(Configuration conf, String jobName) throws IOException {
    this(conf);
    setJobName(jobName);
  }

  Job(Cluster cluster) throws IOException {
    this(cluster, new Configuration());
  }

  Job(Cluster cluster, Configuration conf) throws IOException {
    super(conf, null);
    this.cluster = cluster;
  }

  ...
  public static Job getInstance(Cluster cluster, Configuration conf) 
      throws IOException {
    return new Job(cluster, conf);
  }
```

So you can use:

```
...
Configuration conf = getConf();
Job job = Job.getInstance(new Cluster(conf), conf);
```

Note that instantiating the Job class in this way will create at the same time a connection to the `job tracker` as well.

If you want to defer doing so, you have the option to *lazily initialize* this connection by setting `Cluster` to null when creating the Job object. In this case you will let the Job class to make the connection when it's really needed (see further information [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-1505)) :

```
Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
```